# Displaying coordinates from mysql in a php array in specific way

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What I'm trying to do is to get lat and lon columns from a MySQL table and put it in an array with this format "lat lon".
This is what I have done so far:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "whichever");
    $sql = "SELECT lat, lon FROM whatever";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $latlon = array();
    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
     $latlon[$index] = $row;
     $index++;
    }
    $points = $latlon // consider that this was initially stated as $points= array("lat lon", "lat lon", ..."lat lon")
?>
```

but it just gives me the array this way:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [lat] => 37.9661239 [lon] => 23.7528766 ) [1] => Array ( [lat] => 37.9661321 [lon] => 23.7528387 )
```

when I use `print_r($points)`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(lat, ' ', lon) AS latlon FROM whatever`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
     $latlon[$index] = $row['lat'] . ' ' . $row['lon'];
     $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "whichever");
    $sql = "SELECT lat, lon FROM whatever";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $latlon = array();
    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $latlon[$index] = $lat . ' ' . $lon;
    $index++;
    }
    $points = $latlon // consider that this was initially stated as $points= array("lat lon", "lat lon", ..."lat lon")
?>
```